# Adding 'CASE WHEN' to codeigniter CI_DB_mysql_driver object's ar_select key

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to add a case when statement to CI_DB_mysql_driver object. I tried the following code

```
$this->db->select("CASE WHEN colum1 >0 THEN 'sl' ELSE colum1 END AS colum1");
```

When I run it query is generated as

```
`CASE` WHEN colum1 >0 THEN 'sl' ELSE colum1 END AS colum1
```

and it generates sql error.

Comment: What sql error is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off automatic query escaping.

```
$this->db->select("CASE WHEN colum1 >0 THEN 'sl' ELSE colum1 END AS colum1", FALSE);
```

Comment: Can we do query escaping in this case?

Comment: I think you could protect field names by adding the backticks yourself. I don't remember ever trying this so experimentation may be required.